# How to typehint the return value of a function that takes other functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a function that accepts other functions, and would like to type-hint the return value of this "wrapper" function.  The function is similar to this below, but with a lot more logic specific to the use case.  That said, this function is also pretty handy:

```
def guard(func, default: WhatGoesHere = None) -> Optional[WhatGoesHere]:
    try:
        return func()
    except:
        return default
```

The function is used like this, with existing typehinted functions as well as the occasional lambda:

```
def difficult_math() -> int:
    return e^(pi * i) / 0

if res := guard(difficult_math):
   ...

if res := guard(lambda: x/3):
   ...
```

Comment: `Callable` is what you're after. I'd suggest having a look over the `typing` docs

Comment: I'm confused then, isn't the return value dependant on the function being passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
from typing import Callable, Optional, TypeVar

R = TypeVar('R')

def guard(func: Callable[[], R], default: R = None) -> Optional[R]:
    try:
        return func()
    except:
        return default
```

If your function would be taking `*args, **kwargs` you can extend this with `ParamSpec`. And additional positional parameters you'd want to include `Concatenate`.

Comment: This looks right, for the simple use case of guard.  I really thought it was harder, and the examples just made it look worse than it was!

Comment: Just curious - is one `TypeVar("T")` pretty much the same as any other, and its really just a matter of having enough distinct ones to annotate the function?  Something like `f(a: T, b:U) -> V`?

Comment: Pretty much, but that's if the type is unknown or dependant on another input. Most cases you should be able to assign it an expected type.